# My Qt5 executable does not run outside of Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt5

I have done a big project with Qt5 and visual Studio 2010. Everything is well inside of visual studio using the run button.

But my goal is of course to release it to other persons, without visual studio.

My problem is: I can't get the .exe run outside of visual studio. I was asked for several dll's at first, I found them all in the Qt5 bin folder.

But know I got rid of those messages, when I wan't to open my exe, nothing happens. 
Just nothing.....

I cannot even find my exe in the windows task manager.

Does someone here know an answer to that issue?

Comment: You should link statically to Qt5. Don't know how to do it in VC.

Comment: No, you cannot use static linking unless your Qt was built statically. Plus there are some licensing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dll files that are loaded during runtime and don't give you any error, warning or whatsoever when not present (also totally transparent to dependency walker). Such is the `platforms\qwindows.dll` - note that it must be in a `platforms\` subfolder relative to the executable. You might also be missing `libEGL.dll` and `libGLESv2.dll`.

Comment: Yes I think you are right ! I have tried to put my exe in the qt bin folder and it works! But I cannot find the subfolder you're talking about. 
I'm using Qt5.
Do you know how I could know which dll's my program is trying to load ? 

Thank you for your answer ! The problem is not far from solved now !

Comment: The one missing was libEGL.dll
Thank you ! you helped a lot !

Comment: The three dlls that are loaded during runtime are the platform plugin, ligEGL and libGLESv2 - the platform plugin is originally in `qtbase/plugins/platforms`. You can copy it from there and put in the folder of your application, just remember to put it with the platforms folder itself. The rest of the dlls need to be in the same path as the exe, only the platform plugin needs a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Walker is not very useful in this case as it shows very strange dll files missing: API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL etc.

You can use Qt5.x cmd prompt ( 5.x is the version that you are using) and run windeployqt.exe from your build directory. It will automatically find and copy all necessary dll files to your output directory.