# Qt distribute application for windows on qt 5.0.2

Tags: qt, compiler-construction

I have tried to distribute an application that I wrote in Qt creator without success.

I compiled and with dependency walker found all the DLL files that are required, I created a folder and copied the exe and the dll in it and everything works on my local computer.

I copied all the files into a different computer and each time I try to execute it I get an error message that the program was terminated unexpectantly

I tried to compile different programs (examples) and done the same copy/paste and they are all ending with the same error.

I rather not to use static linking because of possible licensing issues

I have looked into other Stack Overflow responses and they are all the same.. copy the DLLs into the folder and it should work... I just can't figure out why I get the error.

Even tried on same windows as well as different version (I am compiling on windows7 64, tried on win7 32, win XP, and win 8)

**EDIT**

This is the list of DLLs that I am adding

```
04/11/2013  12:20 PM         2,106,216 D3DCompiler_43.dll
04/11/2013  12:20 PM        18,025,758 icudt49.dll
04/11/2013  12:20 PM         3,090,303 icuin49.dll
04/11/2013  12:20 PM         1,808,899 icuuc49.dll
04/11/2013  12:22 PM            99,328 libEGL.dll
04/11/2013  12:24 PM           115,200 libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll
04/11/2013  12:22 PM           968,704 libGLESv2.dll
04/11/2013  12:24 PM           895,488 libstdc++-6.dll
04/11/2013  12:24 PM            68,608 libwinpthread-1.dll
04/11/2013  12:25 PM         4,279,808 Qt5Core.dll
04/11/2013  12:23 PM         3,493,376 Qt5Gui.dll
04/11/2013  12:23 PM           663,552 Qt5Multimedia.dll
04/11/2013  12:23 PM           105,472 Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
04/11/2013  12:23 PM         1,130,496 Qt5Network.dll
04/11/2013  12:23 PM           300,032 Qt5OpenGL.dll
04/11/2013  12:23 PM         1,893,376 Qt5Script.dll
04/11/2013  12:24 PM         5,210,624 Qt5Widgets.dll
```

**EDIT**

I figured out, I was missing a folder called "platform" and to copy in it `qminimal.dll` and `qwindows.dll`

I had tried to copy those file directly into the app folder, but it didn't work, I guess they had to have their own folder.

This can be now closed

Comment: Are you sure you got all the dlls? And the right ones?

Comment: Yes, used dependency walker and it executes on my computer in a separated folder

Comment: Deploying with Qt on Windows is hell, but it can be done.  Are the Qt DLLs you copy the same configuration (debug vs. release) as your executable?

Comment: yes, I did that mistake once and it was requesting the DLL ending with "d"

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771019/my-qt5-executable-does-not-run-outside-of-visual-studio-2010/15771132#15771132

Comment: I saw that one.  Already included those files thanks to dependency walker.  Plus it did ask me for them before even start.  But again, it starts on my computer from a folder

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any problems running applications on other machines. Also using windows, but I build Qt myself without webkit to remove the large dependencies.

Comment: I saw the steps to build it, but it is a hell for upgrades (I.E. I wrote in 5.0.1 and we are already at 5.0.2)

Comment: On the development machine, can you launch your executable from the desktop, i.e., *not* from within Qt but by clicking on the application icon?  This has been a crucial test for me in the past.

Comment: Not to mention how tediously slow it can be.... BTW what about the runtimes, e.g. msvc or mingw or whatever compiler you are using?

Comment: @MattPhillips Yes, and it works.

Comment: @ddriver I am using the one that comes with qt, I believe mingw.  Cannot find a DLL for it and dependency walker doesn't show it as needed.

Comment: This is certainly strange, maybe there is something wrong on your target machine? Did you try more than one that is not your PC?

Comment: The only other thing I could think of at this point is 32- vs. 64 bit but you appear to have ruled that out too.

Comment: the compiler that I downloaded is a 32bit (didn't see the 64), and I have tested 3 other computers (XP, win7 64m win7 32)

Comment: Well, I am officially out of ideas, maybe you need to try a different build. 5.0.2 comes in 4 flavors, plus you can always try to build it yourself.

Comment: I tried 5.0.1 first.  I am using Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7, 650 MB) because I do not have VS

Comment: You can get VS express - its free.

Comment: Downloading VS Express.  But shouldn't be working without ?

Comment: What is the exact error message. When the DLL is missing, it will inform you exactly what the expected DLL name is. In your case that is completely different issue unless it tells you the name of DLL.

Comment: It doesn't show the missing DLL, just that the program was terminated.  Even using examples codes I receive the errors

Comment: The message that appears on any other computer is:  this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Answer (score 0):

Small addition which I faced recently. If you compiling on Windows 7 (VS 2012) x32, you should look carefully on bootstrap settings in VS. Otherwise your application will not work on anything below Vista and you will have pretty weird error that 'It's not a Win32 application'. On latest VS2012 service pack MS added an XP-type bootstrap.